# jquery .val() sets different values than provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a django form, that needs to be filled with a button click. The form renders like following:

```
<input type="text" id="start_date">
<input type="text" id="end_date">
<input type="submit" id="submit_first" value="POST">
<button id="submit_second">Generate</button>
```

The jquery for setting the values in the text fields when clicked `submit_second` is as follows:

```
$('#submit_second').click(function(){
    $('#id_start_date').val({{start_date}});
    $('#id_end_date').val({{end_date}});

    $('#submit_first').click();
})
```

The start_date and end_date variable holds some date strings that are passed as context from the view and outputs their true values( `eg: 2015-07-7`) in the template but sets different values in the text fields when triggered the jquery function(`eg: 1990`).

Comment: What does the generated code look like? Is it `$('#id_start_date').val(2015-07-7);`? How should JavaScript know that `2015-07-7` is a **date** as opposed to **subtracting** `7` and `7` from `2015`? You probably want to pass a **string**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is the rendered script is like `$('#id_start_date').val(2015-07-7);` where `2015-07-7` will be considered as a mathematical formula and the equation will be processed and the result of the operation is set as the input's value.

Since you want to render the value as it is, you need to treat the value like a string, so try

```
$('#submit_second').click(function () {
    $('#id_start_date').val('{{start_date}}');
    $('#id_end_date').val('{{end_date}}');

    $('#submit_first').click();
})
```

Comment: Seriously, feeling so dumb right now. Thanks boss!!

Answer (score 0):

the `.val()` method retrieves the value of an element.
You should use the `.text()` method.

```
$('#submit_second').click(function(){
    $('#id_start_date').text({{start_date}});
    $('#id_end_date').text({{end_date}});

    $('#submit_first').click();
})
```

Comment: `.val` also **sets** the value of `<input>` elements, and that's what the OP has (even though the selector doesn't match...).